# Change to a remote position

Tags: developer, telecommute

I work as a developer in the UK but I am from another country. I have been working for the same company for nearly two years now.

The thing is that I am a bit tired of living here and I really want to go back to my country. I tempted to gather my manager and explain this to him and see if there is a possibility to work remotely from home (which I know it is absolutely possible not only because of the type of work but also cause there are already people doing it particularly old employees).

I know they are happy with me in terms of the work I do, interaction with other colleagues, etc. and on the other side, I cannot complain of anything. The atmosphere and the people I work with is perfect.

It seems a bit crazy to abandon a job that you are pleased with but there are other reasons behind this such as loneliness, a bit of anxiety, homesick, family... well, obvious reasons I suppose.

Just dropping this message here to see if I can get some useful tips or ideas on how to move forward this matter.

Comment: `I tempted to gather my manager and explain this to him and see if there is a possibility to work remotely from home` Don't just sit there and think, go and talk to your manager.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Indeed, I will do it but I am just asking how I can articulate this better.

Comment: If you're an EU National, have you considered how a 'no deal' Brexit may affect this?  E.G will you have a right to work in the UK from abroad after Brexit in a worst-case scenario?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yeah, I did for my actual company a few times it was good (short-term like one-two weeks, though). No big problems and the work was done and the communication was perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always ask. I've personally had success doing this in the past. If you're a valued employee, it will often be easier for them to be flexible on this sort of arrangement rather than hire someone new. To me, the key is to consider your employers' potential questions and come up with good answers. Some examples would be:

- How will you handle meetings?
- What will be your hours?
- Can you visit the office if needed?

Answer (score -2):

When you ask, three pieces of advice

- Don't whine
- Don't whine

and most importantly

- Don't whine

Be very careful that you don't give any "reasons" that you "want or need" to move to another country.

Nobody cares if you are homesick or whatever else. Nobody cares about your reasons.

They just want to know that you will *get more work done than now*.

Just state simply and directly

> Hey boss - do you mind if I work remotely for the next six months?  I'll be in Hungary.

Leave it at that.  Make it a fait accompli.

Most importantly, don't whine. Talk from a position of strength.

Emphasize that you'll be able to work harder and that, ***of course you will keep identical hours to the office***.

## The number one reason some teams DON'T go for remotes is that the remote workers keep oddball hours.

*Don't* give your boss a need to disallow it, due to that.

Again, *don't* talk about your reasons why you want this benefit.  Nobody cares.

*Do* talk about the advantages to the company.

Good luck!